# How to extract the text private and public key from ECDsa or ECDsaCng object?

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography, .net-6.0, ecdsa

When creating an ECDSA object, and trying to extract the private and public key objects it returns a `byte[]`. But when trying to convert it to a string, the output it gives doesn't look right.

```cs
// Creating the object with default parameters
ECDsa ecdSa = ECDsa.Create(ECCurve.NamedCurves.nistP256);

// Export parameters
ECParameters ecParamters = ecdSa.ExportParameters(true);

// Private Key
byte[] privateKey = ecParamters.D;

// Public key params
ECPoint publicKey = ecParamters.Q;

// Coordinates
byte[] publicKeyX = publicKey.X; // What format? int, double, etc
byte[] publicKeyY = publicKey.Y; // What format? int, double, etc
```

Above `ECParameters` give access to the `curve`, `D (private key)` and `Q (public key)`.

Any idea what sort of formatting is being used in these byte arrays? how can we convert it to a string format, eg: private and public keys to `PKCS#8`?

Comment: Which byte arrays? Are you talking about the `ECParameters` structure?

Comment: Hi @Corey, I have added more info to the description. Does it make sense?

Comment: That's what I thought. `D` is the n-bit private key, while `X` and `Y` are coordinates on the curve - 32-byte (256-bit) integers in this case. There's not much more you can get from the raw data, so it's not much use to you beyond key persistence. Go with Topaco's answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

D is simply the `raw` private key, X and Y are the two coordinates of the `raw` public key. These are 32 bytes each for P-256.

Since .NET Core 3.0 the *direct* export of private ECDSA keys in PKCS#8 format ([`ExportPkcs8PrivateKey()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.asymmetricalgorithm.exportpkcs8privatekey?view=netcore-3.0)) and SEC1 format ([`ExportECPrivateKey()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.ecdsa.exportecprivatekey?view=netcore-3.0)) is supported and of public ECDSA keys in X.509 format ([`ExportSubjectPublicKeyInfo()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.asymmetricalgorithm.exportsubjectpublickeyinfo?view=netcore-3.0)). A detour via `ExportParameters()` is not necessary! The exported keys are DER encoded.

Example:

```cs
ECDsa ecdsa = ECDsa.Create(ECCurve.NamedCurves.nistP256);

byte[] privatePkcs8Der = ecdsa.ExportPkcs8PrivateKey();
byte[] privateSec1Der = ecdsa.ExportECPrivateKey();
byte[] publicX509Der = ecdsa.ExportSubjectPublicKeyInfo();
```

The conversion from DER to PEM encoding is trivial: Base64 encode, insert a newline after every 64 characters and add the format specific header and footer. Alternatively you can use BouncyCastle (e.g. for PKCS#8 via `Org.BouncyCastle.Utilities.IO.Pem.PemWriter`):

```cs
using Org.BouncyCastle.Utilities.IO.Pem;
using System.IO;
...
StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
PemWriter pemWriter = new PemWriter(stringWriter);
pemWriter.WriteObject((PemObjectGenerator)new PemObject("PRIVATE KEY", privatePkcs8Der)); // SEC1: EC PRIVATE KEY, X.509: PUBLIC KEY
Console.WriteLine(stringWriter.ToString());
```

Since .NET 5 the PEM encoding is also *directly* supported, but only for the import: [`ImportFromPem()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.asymmetricalgorithm.importfrompem?view=net-5.0).

Note similar support exists for ECDH and RSA keys.

Comment: And .NET 7 preview releases already have PEM export built in (e.g. ExportSubjectPublicKeyInfoPem). And we also have a built-in PEM reader/writer, we call it PemEncoding (.NET 5+)